# Implementation of periodic task in android

Tags: java, android, timer, android-activity, timertask

I want to create a small android app that would show the system time in periodic intervals after clicking on a button ( i.e. setting the activity up )...The code for button creation and setting the periodic activity via **Intent** goes like this :

```
package com.example.timeupdate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
TextView show;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle I_Love_Biriyani) {
    super.onCreate(I_Love_Biriyani);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.pressButton);
    show = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.Show);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent openTimeUpdater = new Intent("com.example.timeupdate.TIMEUPDATER");
            startActivity(openTimeUpdater);

        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

And here is the code for repeating the timer( for say 5 seconds ) where I used **TimerTask** class to perform the job :

```
package com.example.timeupdate;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimeUpdater extends Activity {

    TextView Show;

    TimerTask timer= new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Date d = new Date();
            Show.setText(""+d);
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle hotovaga) throws IllegalStateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(hotovaga);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_update);

        Show = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time);

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer , 0 , 5000);

    }


}
```

After clicking on the button the time is shown only once then application is getting stopped showing a dialog-message. Need explanations to do this job in the same fashion.

Comment: what kind of task are you trying to achieve. you can use a timer or a handler. BTW you have two timer objects in your second activity

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an UI element inside non-UI thread.

```
Show.setText(""+d);
```

Instead, wrap it up in `runOnUiThread` interface to get proper output.

Use below code for your `TimeUpdater` class

```
public class TimeUpdater extends Activity {


    TextView Show = null;
    Calendar c; 
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;

    TimerTask timer= new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Show.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }
            });
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_update);

        Show = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time);

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer , 0 , 5000);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an actual Timer (java.util.Timer) in conjunction with runOnUiThread() is one way to solve this issue, and below is an example of how to implement it.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

private Timer myTimer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}

private void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    //This method runs in the same thread as the UI. 
    // Set your textView data here.              

    //Do something to the UI thread here

    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use PeriodicTask from Play-Service, it is the newest tool  from Google to schedule a job background.

Comment: It would save the readers some googling if you included a link to docs :)